# Covert HTML tags between <code></code> to special characters

Tags: php, regex, htmlspecialchars

I'm writing a blogging web app using PHP, I would like the blog to be able to show some code snippets to the audiences

I publish new articles to the blog using markdown files, so after converting from markdown to HTML the result should look something like this

```
<h3>This is sample HTML Coding</h3>

<pre><code>
    <html>
        <body>
            Hello World
        </body>
    </html>
</code></pre>

<h3>This is another sample HTML Coding</h3>

<pre><code>
    <html>
        <body>
            Another Hello World
        </body>
    </html>
</code></pre>
```

I cannot just simply use PHP function like `htmlspecialchars()` because I need those e.g. headings and code blocks to be rendered.  I should in fact need to convert only all special characters **between** `<code></code>`

Right now the only thing I can think of is using RegEx, I came up with 2 choices of direction which I think it might be possible.

1. Match all `<`, `>`, `</` only between `<code></code>` and use `preg_replace()` with **special characters** on each of those.
2. Match all characters between each `<code></code>` (because I would have several code blocks on each article) then use `preg_replace()` with `htmlspecialchars()`

**Please advise**

1. Which choice should I use?
2. What is RegEx to do the job?

**P.S.**

I put the HTML result from markdown at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yG5tF7) I tried some RegEx e.g. `(?<=<code>)[<](?=<\/code>)/g` for choice 1, and `(?<=<code>)[\s\S]*(?=<\/code>)/g` for choice 2, but they both are not working.

**Edited**

This is expected result I wish.

```
    <h3>This is sample HTML Coding</h3>

    <pre><code>
        &lt;html>
            &lt;body&gt;
                Hello World
            &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt;
    </code></pre>

    <h3>This is another sample HTML Coding</h3>

    <pre><code>
        &lt;html&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;
                Another Hello World
            &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt;
    </code></pre>
```

Comment: What would be the expected output for the above html code?

Comment: I wrote the expected result in the edited part, thanks.

Comment: @Wyzard, I'm using built-in markdown of Fat-Free framework, I got result from conversion just like the given example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you're wanting to do this, but you should use a callback function here:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=<code>).*?(?=</code>)~s', 
      function($m) {
         return htmlentities($m[0]);
      }, $html);
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/170467)

Comment: I still confuse about your RegEx (especially the `~` instead of `/`)  because it was not working in **regex tester** but when put everthing all together in PHP it just works like magic, but the other given answers such as `(?<=<code>).*?(?=<\/code>)`[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG5tF7/2) works in the **regex tester** but I really don't know yet how to combine it to PHP, would you please explain me more or give me some links I can learn more about it.

Comment: `~` is a delimiter. See PHP delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match all the characters which are just inside the `<code></code>` tags,

```
(?s)(?<=<code>).*?(?=<\/code>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yG5tF7/2)

Comment: then only `s` would be enough.

Comment: If I have 2 code blocks on the article just like given example, do I have to loop 2 times to use `preg_replace()`? I meant, I don't quite understand the actual process.

Comment: Unless the code snippet *contains* a `<code>...</code>` element…

Answer (score 0):

You're writing your posts in Markdown, right?  Markdown supports [code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode).  Use them.

When you want to include a code snippet, indent it four spaces — just like you do here on StackOverflow — and Markdown will generate a `<code>` element and automatically escape any angle brackets and ampersands within it.  You don't have to do any post-processing of your own to figure out which part of the HTML belongs to a code snippet, because Markdown already knows.

Basically, just do the same thing you did to write the HTML in your question above.  That's Markdown.